# How to run the scripts in html document and get resulting document in node?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I have a **string** in **node** with a **html document** like this:

```html
<p id="text">First text</p>
<script>
    document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = 'Second text';
</script>
```

And I want to get the **resulting html document** after running the scripts like this:

```html
<p id="text">Second text</p>
<script>
    document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = 'Second text';
</script>
```

I don't know how to do it and I didn't found anything that can help.
The scripts are more complex, this is an example

Comment: So, you want to execute your script tag once before serving your html document to client ?

Comment: Can you explain what does this line means, "I have a string in node"? i am not getting this line.

Comment: Yes, I wan't to make a capture of the html and I need to run scripts before

Comment: are you using any kind of template engine ?

Comment: @SanskarBansal, it isn't a file, it's a template string with html in it

Comment: No, it's just a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look for a package called `JSDOM`.

```js
const jsdom = require("jsdom");
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;
const dom = new JSDOM(`<p id="text">First text</p>
<script>
    document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = 'Second text';
</script>
`, { runScripts: "dangerously" }
); 

console.log(dom.window.document.body.innerHTML);
```

You can check more details regarding this package on this url: https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsdom

Comment: Now you can do whatever you want with this ```dom.window.document.body.innerHTML```, you can save it in file, serve it to your clients, i guess this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks, it was exactly what I was looking for